# How to automatically continuously poll FTP server without human intervention

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, ftp

**My Requirement**

1. I need to keep watching FTP server
2. and whenever a new file comes in to the pre-configured location Read the file(s) and process

**My current logic**

I have placed an Angular Service running in my home page (ASP.Net MVC .cshtml file)

```
<div ng-app="myApp1" ng-controller="FTPCtrl">

        </div>
```

With this the FTP processing (reading, writing,...)  is happening.

**My Problem**

But the FTP process will happen only if someone opens the home page.

**My Query**

- What is to be done so that the Angularjs service is called continuously without any human intervention?
- Where should I place or call this Angularjs service?

Comment: It may help to know what you are trying to do and why? Have done this previously with IIS by writing a .Net module - [FTP Custom Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/ftpserver/customfeatures/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is implementing using Angular, then it sounds like you mean you're doing FTP requests from the browser, or at least have logic in the Angular/JavaScript (browser-based) code which causes the FTP requests to happen?

If you want this work to execute on a regular schedule without user intervention, then remove it to the server-side and put the logic into a Windows Service, or a program triggered by a Windows Scheduled Task. You'll probably have to re-write it in C# or another language.

You can't really automate something which is implemented within a browser - a browser is a GUI tool for manual use by users. JavaScript code within a web page can only run when the user opens the page in a browser and causes it to be executed. By contrast, server-side code can be executed anytime, and potentially without user intervention.

Comment: I see an option Window Service as an option for this requirement. What are the other options related to C# that we have? And which is the best to go for? Please suggest.

Comment: Well I already described the most common two options in my answer - full-on Windows Service, or a little Console app which is triggered on a timer by a Scheduled Task.  Alternatively there are packages such as Hangfire, Quartz and others which allow execution of background tasks to take place within the context of an MVC app, but I don't know if they'd allow for exactly what you need here. There may be other options too - you can easily do a lot of research into this kind of thing online yourself, and find lots of related products, code examples, documentation etc etc.